# Section tag in HTML4 not creating aligned columns

Tags: css, html, html4

I am creating a list of films by decade using the article and section tags. The problem is this: the second and third row align perfectly, while the first row is slightly off. Here is my code:

```
<article id="movies">

<section>
<h3>Three Weeks (1924)</h3>
</section>

<section>
<h3>Leatherstocking (1924)</h3>
</section>

<section>
<h3>Wild Horse Mesa (1925)</h3>
</section>  

</article>
```

it looks like the following:

[image: List of films]

I have it wrapped in a div tag. I looked over the code and everything checks out ok

TIA

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in the image when writing this in JSfiddle. Please can you include any CSS that might be enacting on this?

Comment: I hope you are using some css with this html, and it is probably because of the css.

Comment: Your code as presented does not match your image: https://jsfiddle.net/42x383kr/ . Please provide a [MCVE], including relevant CSS. Breaking down the problem my show you where the issue lies.  Also if you have a "list of films" perhaps a list element (`ul`,`ol` or `dl`) could be more appropriate.

Comment: "SECTION TAG IN **HTML4**"

Comment: Here is some of the CSS:

.center-div
{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 1400px; 
}


p

 {
    font-family: "Tahoma";

    font-size:14;

          color:Black;

}

p.italic 

{
    font-style: italic;
}

h1

{  font-family:"Tahoma";

        color:Black;
}

h2

{  font-family:"Tahoma";

        color:Black;
}

h3

{  font-family:"Tahoma";

        color:Black;
}

Comment: if you are using column css, you have to mind the defaut 1em margin on h3. reset margin to 0 for h3 ... https://jsfiddle.net/o1dqq06L/

Comment: The CSS you have supplied is still not enough to replicate the problem as described : https://jsfiddle.net/42x383kr/1/. You can edit the question to add your css, instead of leaving it in comments. Also you can embed a functional snippet in your question by using the `<>` button in the question editor.

Comment: More CSS, the menu bar:

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000033;
  font-family: Arial;
padding: 0px 70px 0px 70px;
 }

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
 right: 50%;
overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: Before throwing any more random CSS at us, please check that it replicates the issue. Nothing you have provided does so : https://jsfiddle.net/42x383kr/2/ . Use my linked fiddle as a reference to test the CSS you want to check. If we can't replicate the problem, we are left with guesswork/magic/voodoo.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say you know very little about CSS. There is nothing wrong with that. The CSS you are looking for is going to be along the lines of `#movies {}` and/or `#movies > sections {}`, and/or `#movies > sections > h3 {}` . Note that Stack Overflow is not a "General Learning Resource" more a "Specific Problem Solving Resource". Might I suggest a good [CSS Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS)

Comment: @Mary H: Please add the code to your question with edits rather than comments so they'll be easier to see with formatting. Also, <section> doesn't exist in HTML 4 and there really isn't any point in using the HTML 4 DOCTYPE anymore if that's what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please `Run code snippet`. and see the result. As per my understanding I have create this demo.

```css
section { float:left; width:33.33%; background:green }
```

```html
<article id="movies">

<section>
<h3>Three Weeks (1924)</h3>
</section>

<section>
<h3>Leatherstocking (1924)</h3>
</section>

<section>
<h3>Wild Horse Mesa (1925)</h3>
</section>  

</article>
```